# LSTM: output includes both categorical variables and continuous variables

Tags: python, regression, classification, lstm

I would like to run LSTM to do a prediction. Output is high dimensional. Some are continuous outcomes, which should be based on regression; others are categorical outcomes, which should be based on classification.

Is there a way for LSTM to do both at the same time? If so, how shall I tell the algorithm which are continuous outcomes and which are categorical outcomes.

Comment: If the output is n+m dimensions, where n are continuous and m are binary (categorical are almost always one hot encoded), you can take 2 output laters each of n and m units and apply saperate loss functions (mse for continuous and cross entropy for categorical after a sigmoid to keep between 0 and 1, at the most basic level), and back prop. See how multi objective is done in your relevant package